# Encryption type in sharpziplib

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I'm using sharplibzip to zip my files with password. I cannot find, what encryption does it use - I need to know that to decide, if I can be sure no one is able to unzip without knowing the password. I can use very long password in my app too.

**EDIT:** So, this library can use AES encryption, you have ZipEntry.AESKeySize for that. And if you use 128 or longer keysize - that will be practically uncrackable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharpZipLib uses PkzipClassic and AES.

> if I can be sure no one is able to unzip without knowing the password

If you use AES with a key size of 128 or higher, then yes, you can be sure. Please see this article:
http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279619
According to that article, it would take 3.31 * 10<sup>56</sup> years to crack a 256-bit key.

Comment: Yes, I found the way to set encryption type to AES 256. I know, that AES can't be hacked without the password - isn't that true for zipping?

Comment: Well, not that it cannot be done, but it will take unwisely long amount of time.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you use AES 256, then it really takes a very very very large amount of time before it's cracked.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed to be sure!